# Puzzling behaviour from two inverters connected together

Tags: digital-logic

I'm an electronics newbie and I am puzzled by the behaviour of a circuit I have created. I have connected the output of one inverter to the input of another but the behaviour of the circuit is not what I expected. I've included a schematic and two photos of the circuit. The first photo shows the two inverters unconnected and the circuit behaves as I expect it to, that is, LED1 turns off when I press the tactile button. However, in photo 2 you can see that I have connected the output of the first inverter to the input of the second and LED1 is off, but it should be on. Can you explain what is happening?

[image: Inverter Circuit Schematic]
[image: Inverters Unconnected]
[image: Inverters Connected]

Comment: The base of Q1 is always low. Your SW1 does nothing! (Unless something is broken in your ground connections.) So, your schematic isn't showing your actual circuit.

Comment: The base of Q1 goes high when I press SW1 and the LED goes out. I am a little new to drawing schematics.

Comment: well, but if the base goes high, it means it's not directly connected to ground! But in your schematic, it stays connected to ground, no matter whether you press S1 or not. So, it's tied to the same ground potential, always. Whether or not R1 is also connected to ground makes no difference to the ground potential!

Comment: Okay so I have got the schematic wrong, however the actual unconnected inverter circuit works. With SW1 unpressed LED1 stays on, when it is pressed LED1 turns off, which is correct. When I connect the two inverters together LED1 goes off and stays off. If I press the button LED2 turns on.

Comment: So, without us knowing *exactly* what your circuit does, we can't help you – please investigate what your schematic *actually* looks like, and whether all connections on your breadboard actually are reliable. (**A lot** of time has been sunk into solderless breadboard connections simply not being good connections.)

Comment: The circuit is designed to invert its input through one inverter and feed the output of that inverter through another inverter so that the final output always follows the input. I have tested both inverters independently of one another and verified that they work. The problem happens when I connect the output of the first inverter to the input of the second inverter. I have tested each of the connections and they are good.

Comment: yes, but the circuit you show in your schematic has little to do with what you've built and little to do with what it's designed for. So fix your schematic, it's not correctly representing what you've built. Helping you without that is impossible. Full stop.

Comment: Are you really using BC547? If so, you have a swapped emitter with the collector.

Comment: @G36 I just read the datasheet for the BC547 and realized that you're correct. A lesson learned: always read the datasheet. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that the anode (top) of LED1 is connected directly to the base of Q2. When Q1 is off current will flow from R3 through Q2 base to ground. As Q2  is a silicon transistor the voltage on its base will be clamped to about 0.7 V. A red LED needs about 1.8 V to light up so LED1 won't see enough voltage to light up. (Q2 will switch on and off correctly so LED2 will behave as expected.)

To correct this, link LED1 to Q2 with a resistor (e.g. 1 kΩ, depending on the value of Vcc) rather than a wire link. This will allow the voltages on LED1 and the base of Q2 to be different.

Edit: I've removed text about an earlier version of your schematic which no longer applies to the updated version.

Comment: I connected a 220 Ohm resistor from LED1 to Q2 and the circuit works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarioGianota: you could look at this problem as the 2nd inverter having near-zero input impedance, so it's impossible for the 220 ohm output impedance of the first inverter to drive it to the desired voltage range.

Answer (score 1):

The base of Q2 in your schematic will shunt the LED and prevent it from ever turning on. However the second inverter will function coupled to the first. So the output LED2 should function as expected.

I didn’t look at your breadboard implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Schematic seems to be showing only the circuit of second bread board photo.

As per second bread board picture, ...
LED1 is getting clamped by the VBE drop of Q2.  So, LED1 would not glow when its anode is connected to the base of Q2 regardless of the switch position.

As per first bread board picture,...
The switch is off,
The green wire connecting LED1 anode and Q2 base is removed. So, LED1 is no longer clamped by the VBE of Q2. That's why LED1 is glowing. The LED2 is also glowing because Q2 base is left open thus Q2 is OFF.